# Send fb notification from your own website

Tags: javascript, php

I cant seem to figure this out. How can I send a FB notification from my own website? Is there an API or something? A way at all to send FB noifications from an external domain?
Either PHP or JS will do

Comment: Wait... You need a FB SDK API. Create an application and give the necessary permissions

Comment: Perfect thank you. Please post that in an answer and I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have done it buddy. Lemme add the links for you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps you need to follow:

1. You need Facebook API Key, from [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/).
2. Create an Application in Facebook.
3. Give the necessary permissions.
4. Send the notifications from your server using push notifications.

All the details are there in FB SDK.

Comment: Thank you accepting answer in 1 minute.

Comment: @user6031759 You are welcome! :) Thanks again. :)

Comment: Sorry was on the FB page.

Comment: @user6031759 Ha ha.. How is it going? :D